# how to bind an close event to window.open()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function to open a url in a window pop up:

```
function windowPopup(url, width, height) {
  // center 
  var left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2),
      top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);

  handle=window.open(
    url,
    "",
    "menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=" + 
    width + ",height=" + height + ",top=" + top + ",left=" + left
  );
}
```

I want to be able to detect when this window is closed an execute some code. How can I use the handle in the function to bind an unload or close?

I want to know once the window has been closed after someone shares to twitter:

```
windowPopup("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=Check%20out%20this%20website!&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F", 500, 300);
```

### Update

I updated with Lar's suggestion:

```
function windowPopup(url, width, height) {
  // center 
  var left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2),
      top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);



  handle=window.open(
    url,
    "",
    "menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=" + 
    width + ",height=" + height + ",top=" + top + ",left=" + left
  );

  handle.onbeforeunload = function() {
    alert('Bye!');
  }

}
```

While this worked for some pop up windows it didn't work when i closed the twitter window...

Comment: You need to listen to the "onbeforeunload" event and then try to prevent default action and use your own. Are you trying to make a mallware or what?

Comment: Maybe use jQuery unload event? https://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: why would you think i'm trying to make malware?!

Comment: Opening a new window every time you try to close it? If that new page has this code also, will create a infinite loop of close-reopen windows. That's why I think this. What is the purpose anyway?

Comment: ok whatever dinca

Answer (score 1):

You’re looking for the `beforeunload` event:

```
handle.onbeforeunload = function() {
  console.log('Bye!');
}
```

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for that however this isn't working for when I load a twitter window. I'll update the question and add this in